# ZTE F609, telnet issue

Tags: passwords, login, modem, telnet

I have modem ZTE F609 (Software Version V7.0.10P7N1) and I can't telnet it because of wrong login/password. I tried many different variants (all that Google and my imagination provided me:D), like **root/Zte521** (works for F660V3 and F660V5.2), **root/root** (works for F660V2), **root/admin, root/Telkom135** and another - noone worked. If I type login **'root'** - system demands a password. If I type any other login - system returns an error and says that login is incorrect. So at least I know that login **'root'** is right:D
Reset doesn't help. Modem configuration file is encrypted (AES + zlib) so I can't just get xml-file (but I'm trying:D) and look what correct login/password are.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Maybe someone knows what login/password could be correct?
Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tnx to @streetster try key below to decrypt config.bin

```
strings -32 cspd | grep ZTE
ZTE%FN$GponNJ025678b02a85c63c706
```

Edit: that key does not work dont know why, key for telnet access is
serial number of your device